# Ruby: Understanding _why's cloaker method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand _why's `cloaker` method which he wrote about in "[A Block Costume](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/redhanded/inspect/aBlockCostume.html)":

```
class HTML
  def cloaker &blk
    (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
      # ... rest of method
    end
  end
end
```

I realise that `class << self; self; end` opens up the Eigenclass of `self`, but I've never seen anyone do this inside an instance method before. What is `self` at the point where we do this? I was under the impression `self` should be the receiver that the method was called on, but `cloaker` is called from inside `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing tag, text = nil, &blk
  # ...
  if blk
    cloaker(&blk).bind(self).call
  end
  # ...
end
```

So what is `self` inside the `method_missing` call? And what is `self` when we call:

```
((class << self; self; end).class_eval)
```

inside the `cloaker` method?

Basically, I want to know whether we are we opening the Eignenclass of the HTML class, or if we are doing it to a specific instance of the HTML class?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. `method_missing` is an instance method, so `self` refers to the specific instance and `class << self; self; end` returns the Eigenclass of that instance.

Comment: Note that the official term is `singleton_class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `cloaker` method, `self` will be an instance of HTML since you'll call that on a object, so you're effectively creating a Singleton Method on HTML class instances. For instance:

```
class HTML
  def cloaker &blk
    (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
      def new_method
      end
    end
  end
end

obj = HTML.new
obj.cloaker
p HTML.methods.grep /new_method/  # []
p obj.singleton_methods # [:new_method]
```

**Edit**

Or as  Jörg W Mittag commented , just a pre-1.9 way of the calling `"Object#define_singleton_method"`

Comment: Of course, as of Ruby 1.9, that's basically just `def cloaker(&blk) define_singleton_method(:new_method, &blk) end`